# release memory in the model when using mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, ios7, uiviewcontroller, model, automatic-ref-counting

I have some controllers and some data in model which connected with this controller. I don't need to consider when this controllers release in ios7. (viewdidunload is Deprecated!) So when should I remove these data in the model?

Any ideas without breaking mvc?

is dealloc a good idea?

thanks~

Answer (score 0):

The details provided are not very specific.

But if you're using Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) dealloc is the wrong way.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html